# Call to fail() fails

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to setup a new puppetmaster (v5.0.1) and all goes well, except for one thing.

I can't call `fail()` in my manifests. When it tries to run any `fail()` function, it throws an Evaluation error.

This happens in manifests and with puppet apply as well.

```
$ puppet apply -e 'fail("Failure")' --trace
```

Will return the following error and trace:

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call,
>   Failure  at line 1:1 on node ***
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/functions/fail.rb:3:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/functions.rb:174:in`
>   block (2 levels) in newfunction'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in
>   `profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in`
>   profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/functions.rb:167:in
>   `block in newfunction' :1:in`stack'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/puppet_stack.rb:30:in
>   `eval'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/puppet_stack.rb:30:in`
>   stack'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/runtime3_support.rb:316:in
>   `call_function'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/evaluator_impl.rb:949:in`
>   call_function_with_block'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/evaluator_impl.rb:918:in
>   `eval_CallNamedFunctionExpression'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:48:in`
>   block in visit_this'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:42:in
>   `each'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:42:in`
>   visit_this'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:92:in
>   `visit_this_1'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/evaluator_impl.rb:81:in`
>   evaluate' :in `stack'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/puppet_stack.rb:30:in`
>   eval'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/puppet_stack.rb:30:in
>   `stack'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/evaluator_impl.rb:723:in`
>   eval_Program'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:48:in
>   `block in visit_this'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:42:in`
>   each'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:42:in
>   `visit_this'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/visitor.rb:92:in`
>   visit_this_1'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/evaluator/evaluator_impl.rb:81:in
>   `evaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/pops/parser/evaluating_parser.rb:63:in`
>   evaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/ast/pops_bridge.rb:132:in
>   `evaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/ast.rb:31:in`
>   safeevaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource/type.rb:136:in
>   `evaluate_code'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/resource.rb:79:in`
>   block in evaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in
>   `profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in`
>   profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/resource.rb:71:in
>   `evaluate'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:589:in`
>   evaluate_main'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:164:in
>   `block (2 levels) in compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in`
>   profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in
>   `profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:164:in`
>   block in compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:65:in
>   `override'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:310:in`
>   override'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:153:in
>   `compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:33:in`
>   compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:282:in
>   `block (2 levels) in compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in`
>   profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in
>   `profile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:280:in`
>   block in compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:224:in
>   `block in benchmark'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in`realtime'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:223:in
>   `benchmark'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:278:in`
>   compile'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:52:in
>   `find'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:195:in`
>   find'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:258:in
>   `block in main'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:65:in`
>   override'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:310:in
>   `override'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:229:in`
>   main'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:170:in
>   `run_command'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:358:in`
>   block in run'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:666:in
>   `exit_on_fail'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:358:in`
>   run'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:132:in
>   `run'
>   /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:72:in`
>   execute' /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet:5:in `'

I'm sure it's me, but I can't figure out what causes this.

Comment: Call to fail() fails: so it is working! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fail()` function is working as designed but the error message is confusing.

The `fail()` function is just a wrapper around `raise Puppet::ParseError`. Normally, `Puppet::ParseError` is raised when a Puppet function is *not* doing what it is supposed to do. In that context, the message `Error while evaluating a Function Call` makes sense.

Here, however, the error is raised because the function is doing exactly what it *is* supposed to do - raising an error for you. So, it is not an "error while evaluating a function call".

It has always been like this though.

Comment: I think what threw him off was the log converting the Ruby `ParseError` exception type. The message is showing up in the first line though, but can be misinterpreted as part of a sentence. At least that would throw me off.